# Traefik entrypoints and default certificate

Tags: ssl, traefik

**Question 1**

https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/entrypoints/#default-certificate seems to indicate that if I do not specify any `certFile` or `keyFile`, a self-signed certificate will be generated by Traefik, and used instead.

> There can only be one defaultCertificate set per entrypoint. Use a single set of square brackets [ ], instead of the two needed for normal certificates. **If no default certificate is provided, a self-signed certificate will be generated by Traefik, and used instead.**

However, when I try this and enter https://localhost/whoami I get an SSL error by Chrome (ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR). Logs also show `level=error msg="failed to load X509 key pair: tls: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input"`. Have I misunderstood the configuration in that documentation?

This is the code I have to test this.

**test.yml**

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
      labels:
        - "traefik.port=8080"
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/traefik"
    networks:
      - traefiknet
  whoami:
    image: emilevauge/whoami
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.port=80"
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/whoami"
    networks:
      - traefiknet
networks:
  traefiknet:
```

**traefik.toml**

```
logLevel = "DEBUG"

defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[api]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
      entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
      [entryPoints.https.tls.defaultCertificate]

[docker]
  endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
  watch = true
  swarmMode = true
  network = "test_traefiknet"
```

**Start with:**

```
docker stack deploy -c test.yml test
```

**Question 2**

Note that I also tested to do like it reads on this page: https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/entrypoints/#static-certificates

> If an empty TLS configuration is provided, default self-signed certificates are generated.

However, that also did not work. My question is however, what is the difference between this configuration and the configuration shown in question 1 in the toml file?

Answer (score 2):

I found out the answer. I needed to remove `[entryPoints.https.tls.defaultCertificate]`. Unfortunately I did not find the documentation very clear in this regard.